# how to re-run the "curl" command automatically when the error occurs

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Sometimes when I execute a bash script with the `curl` command to upload some files to my ftp server, it will return some error like:

```
56 response reading failed
```

and I have to find the wrong line and re-run them manually and it will be OK.

I'm wondering if that could be re-run automatically when the error occurs.

---

My scripts is like this:

```
#there are some files(A,B,C,D,E) in my to_upload directory,
# which I'm trying to upload to my ftp server with curl command
for files in `ls` ;
    do curl -T $files ftp.myserver.com --user ID:pw ;
done
```

But sometimes A,B,C, would be uploaded successfully, only D were left with an "error 56", so I have to rerun curl command manually.  Besides, as Will Bickford said, I prefer that no confirmation will be required, because I'm always asleep at the time the script is running. :)

Comment: You can set it up to run until it succeeds, but that won't help if you don't fix the problem.

Comment: I'm confused, are you just looking to rerun the failed curl commands until they succeed, or the whole script?

Comment: yes,because most times they would succeed after I reran them several times,so that's why I want them to be rerun automatically

Answer (score 54):

Here's a bash snippet I use to perform exponential back-off:

```
# Retries a command a configurable number of times with backoff.
#
# The retry count is given by ATTEMPTS (default 5), the initial backoff
# timeout is given by TIMEOUT in seconds (default 1.)
#
# Successive backoffs double the timeout.
function with_backoff {
  local max_attempts=${ATTEMPTS-5}
  local timeout=${TIMEOUT-1}
  local attempt=1
  local exitCode=0

  while (( $attempt < $max_attempts ))
  do
    if "$@"
    then
      return 0
    else
      exitCode=$?
    fi

    echo "Failure! Retrying in $timeout.." 1>&2
    sleep $timeout
    attempt=$(( attempt + 1 ))
    timeout=$(( timeout * 2 ))
  done

  if [[ $exitCode != 0 ]]
  then
    echo "You've failed me for the last time! ($@)" 1>&2
  fi

  return $exitCode
}
```

Then use it in conjunction with any command that properly sets a failing exit code:

```
with_backoff curl 'http://monkeyfeathers.example.com/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,phs:) I can feel this is a good script,but I'm a newbie in linux,so it will take me a little time to understand it.

Comment: I wish you could favorite answers because I'm sure I'll come back looking for this later.

Comment: @user1076599 Just to get started, you could paste that into your script somewhere near the top, and remove the `set +e` and `set -e` lines.  Then you'll be able to use it within your script.  To get fancier, you might put it in your shell's login script (`~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or  `~/.bashrc`) instead.

Comment: oh,I can't wait to try this,this time I hope that error 56 would happen again,the more the better

Comment: The "while [[ $attempt < $max_attempts ]]" will cause the program to exit prematurely, because this is actually doing the string comparison rather than comparing integers. And it will always fail if the max_attempts is set to greater than 9.

The solution is to use "while (( $attempt < $max_attempts ))" instead.

Comment: @MLin: Whoops!  Thanks for the catch, incorporated.

Comment: The message ends with 2 dots. This fixes that and adds the unit: `echo "Failure! Retrying in ${timeout}s..." 1>&2`

Comment: Use `attempt=1` to perform exactly the number of attempts defined by `$ATTEMPTS`. With `attempts=0` it does one extra. See https://gist.github.com/fernandoacorreia/b4fa9ae88c67fa6759d271b743e96063

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this will help.  It will try the command, and if it fails, it will tell you and pause, giving you a chance to fix `run-my-script`.

```
COMMAND=./run-my-script.sh 
until $COMMAND; do 
    read -p "command failed, fix and hit enter to try again."
done
```

Comment: You could also use sleep instead of read -p so you wouldn't have to confirm each retry.

Comment: The point of reading is to give him time to fix whatever's wrong.  That'll require an indeterminate time and interaction, so  I don't think there will be a problem with requiring confirmation.

Comment: Hi,kevin.I think your solution can really help me.

Comment: Glad to help.  You could also combine it with phs's function above to run it a few times before asking you to fix it.

Comment: Just put everything you want to rerun into a separate script, including phs's backoff if you want it, and run that script like my example.

Comment: sorry，I made a mistake,I mean I am not try to rerun the whole script

Comment: Well, either way, just put whatever part you want to rerun (phs's function, a simple `curl` call, or an external script) into `$COMMAND`.

Comment: but I'm not sure which part should be rerun,please take a look at the new answer by me

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem where I need to make contact with servers using curl that are in the process of starting up and haven't started up yet, or services that are temporarily unavailable for whatever reason. The scripting was getting out of hand, so I made a dedicated retry tool that will retry a command until it succeeds:

```
#there are some files(A,B,C,D,E) in my to_upload directory,
# which I'm trying to upload to my ftp server with curl command
for files in `ls` ;
    do retry curl -f -T $files ftp.myserver.com --user ID:pw ;
done
```

The curl command has the -f option, which returns code 22 if the curl fails for whatever reason.

The retry tool will by default run the curl command over and over forever until the command returns status zero, backing off for 10 seconds between retries. In addition retry will read from stdin once and once only, and writes to stdout once and once only, and writes all stdout to stderr if the command fails.

Retry is available from here: https://github.com/minfrin/retry